# Remove container with toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show/hide the container with a toggle button ( see code below). It successfully add container for the first click, but doesn't remove properly after the second click. Do anyone knows what is the problem?

```js
let toggle_button = $('#toggle-btn');
let button_container = $('#button-container');

toggle_button.on('click', function (event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  
  let container = get_container();
  toggle_button.toggleClass('toggled');
  
  if (toggle_button.hasClass('toggled')) {
    button_container.after(container);
  } else {
    container.remove();
  }
  
});


function get_container ()
{
  return $('<div/>').css({ 
    width: '100%', height: 'auto', 
    background: 'yellow' 
  }).html('container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-container" style="width:100%;height:auto;background:#000;">
  <button id="toggle-btn">Toggle Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move `container` out of the method so that you retain the reference to the element that was added the previous click.

```js
let toggle_button = $('#toggle-btn')
// Get container
let container = get_container();
toggle_button.on('click', function (event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  
  // Toggle class
  toggle_button.toggleClass('toggled');
  
  if (toggle_button.hasClass('toggled')) {
    toggle_button.after(container);
  } else {
    console.log('Remove container here ...');
    container.remove();
  }
  
});


function get_container ()
{
  return $('<div/>').css({ 
    width: '100%', height: 'auto', 
    background: 'yellow' 
  }).html('container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;background:#000;">
  <button id="toggle-btn">Toggle Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `remove` with the DOM element reference

```js
let toggle_button = $('#toggle-btn')
toggle_button.on('click', function (event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
   
  // Get container
  let container = get_container();
  
  // Toggle class
  toggle_button.toggleClass('toggled');
  
  if (toggle_button.hasClass('toggled')) {
    toggle_button.after(container);
  } else {
    var el = toggle_button.parent().find('div');
    el.remove();
  }
  
});


function get_container ()
{
  return $('<div/>').css({ 
    width: '100%', height: 'auto', 
    background: 'yellow' 
  }).html('container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;background:#000;">
  <button id="toggle-btn">Toggle Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! how about if I add container after another container (see updated code above). How I gonna fix that?

Comment: better you can give a class or id to the container so that you can select that element and remove

Comment: how about if I add container after another container (see updated code above). How I gonna fix that? - In this case `var el = button_container.parent().find('div');`

Answer (score 1):

To remove a specific container, it's better to do it with an identifier.

So your `get_container` becomes:

```
function get_container ()
{
  return $('<div/>').css({ 
    width: '100%', height: 'auto', 
    background: 'yellow' 
  }).html('container').attr('id', 'myContainer');
}
```

And `container.remove();` can change to `$('#'+container.prop('id')).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you're initializing container for every click.

```js
let toggle_button = $('#toggle-btn');
  
// Get container
let container = get_container();

toggle_button.on('click', function (event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

  // Toggle class
  toggle_button.toggleClass('toggled');
  
  if (toggle_button.hasClass('toggled')) {
    toggle_button.after(container);
  } else {
    container.remove();
  }
  
});


function get_container ()
{
  return $('<div/>').css({ 
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto', 
    background: 'yellow' 
  }).html('container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;background:#000;">
  <button id="toggle-btn">Toggle Button</button>
</div>
```